# Synchronization Issue between ARMember and Stripe for Subscription Cancellation

Tags: wordpress, stripe-payments, webhooks

I am experiencing an issue with synchronizing subscription cancellations between the WordPress plugin ARMember and Stripe. When a customer cancels a subscription via my site (using ARMember), the cancellation is correctly processed and recorded in ARMember, but it is not reflected on Stripe.

Here are the details and what I have checked so far:

1. Webhooks between ARMember and Stripe seem to be configured correctly.
2. No errors are reported in the logs of ARMember or Stripe during the cancellation of a subscription.
3. Both ARMember and Stripe's API are up-to-date.
4. The configuration of the ARMember plugin has been checked and seems correct.

However, I noticed in the ARMember logs that the cancellation request is not being sent to Stripe. This seems to be the root of the problem.

My questions are:

- Are there specific configurations or steps I might have missed to ensure proper synchronization between ARMember and Stripe?
- Are there any known issues or bugs with ARMember and Stripe regarding subscription cancellations?
- Do you have any suggestions on what I might try to resolve this issue?

Any help or advice would be greatly appreciated.

Thank you in advance!

I contacted the support of ArMember and Stripe but they don't really help me...